# DEPRECATION NOTICE while trying to launch selenium chrome driver using nightwatch

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

I use chromedriver with nightwatch for my web-ui testing. Things were working until i got this message. How do i get around this issue

```
DEPRECATION NOTICE: Property chrome_driver is deprecated since v0.5.    
Please use the "cli_args" object on the "selenium" property to define 
"webdriver.chrome.driver". E.g.:
{
    "cli_args": {
    "webdriver.chrome.driver": 
        "<VALUE>"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is there in your own question, and in the [example](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#settings-file) on the Nightwatch site:

```
"selenium" : {
  "start_process" : false,
  "server_path" : "",
  "log_path" : "",
  "host" : "127.0.0.1",
  "port" : 4444,
  "cli_args" : {
    "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "<chromedriver path>"
  }
},

[...]
```

Comment: i am confused..why does that happen when i did not had to put in the path at the first place and things where working and i had not changed the settings to get this message.

Comment: i already have the chrome drive path in there..ignore the previous comment

Comment: You never posted your current code, so could you please update your question?

Comment: {
  "src_folders" : ["abc/tests"],
  "output_folder" : "reports",
  "custom_commands_path" : "commands",
  "custom_assertions_path" : "",
  "page_objects_path" : "abc/pages",
  "globals_path" : "./globals.js",

  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : true,
    "server_path" : "abc/bin/selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar",
    "log_path" : "",
    "host" : "127.0.0.1",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "abc/bin/chromedriver",
      "webdriver.ie.driver" : ""
    }
  }
}

Comment: I have realised that things were not working because i had some code that did not work in the global.js ...Thanks for the inputs. I appreciate it